# Python dictionary manipulating items(getting min and max)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

Edit: I removed my explanation part since it was wrong but I still could not be able to convert it.
I was studying list and dictionaries in python and I came accross this code.

```
x = min(minValue, key=lambda b: min([a( \
        myFunction(5,b),c) for c in something]))
```

What is the logical equivalent of this ? It seems simple but I do not get same thing when I try to write it with a different code. . How can write this differently without whole key and lambda thing

Seems like my explanation was wrong. Here is the updated code I try.

```
for b in minValue:
   for c in something: 
       minimum=min(myFunction(5,b),c)
result=min(minimum)
return result
```

Note: By logical equivalent I do not mean the provided code should calculate this exactly like the code I gave but it should have the same output.

Comment: What is the equivalent code you've tried writing? Also some context would help. These things probably aren't called a, b,c etc. Where did you see this code?

Comment: it gets values from list `minValue` and uses them as `b` in calculation and then it checks which calculation gives the smallest result and returns its `b`

Comment: No they are not. I am editing the question to add my code. It is in an exercise of online python teaching  lesson. I changed the variables generalise my understanding

Comment: your function has to return `b`, not `result`

Comment: 1. Your equivalent code is missing another level of function calling: `a(myFunction(5, b), c)`. 2. The 1st code snippet does *not* assign anything to `minValue`. Instead, it loops over the items in an existing `minValue` collection. Each of those items is passed as `b` to the `lambda` function.

Comment: @furas so I need to update b inside the outer for loop? I dont think that is the solution. If I just change the return value I do not think I would accomplish anything since I never changed b and it will be same as returning all values  in minValue

Comment: You need to include the call to a. Your code also has to take into account that the original _constructs a list_ from which it finds a minimum - you don't do that anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' not sure but it can be something like this

```
def example(minValue):

    data = []

    for b in minValue:

        values = []
        for c in something:
            values.append( a(myFunction(5,b),c) )
        result = min(values)

        # keep `result` and `b` which gives this `result`
        data.append( [result, b] )

    # find minimal `result` and `b` which gives this `result`
    x = min(data) # x = [result, b]

    # return `b` 
    return x[1]

#---

x = example(minValue)
```

---

**EDIT:** there can be problem with `min(data)` because `min` will be comparing `result` and `b` and oryginal version compare only `result`. It may need version without `min()` but with:

```
if result < min_result: 
   min_result = result
   min_b = b
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
def key(val):

    min_c = something[0]
    min_result = a(myFunction(5,val),min_c)

    for c in something[1:]:

        result = a(myFunction(5,val),c)

        if result < min_result:
            min_result = result
            #min_c = c

    return min_result


def example(minValue):

    min_b = minValue[0]
    min_result = key(min_b)

    for b in minValue[1:]:

        result = key(b)

        if result < min_result:
            min_result = result
            min_b = b

    return min_b

#---

x = example(minValue)
```

Comment: Why are you putting b back into the list?

Comment: to find minimal `result` and its `b` because I have to return `b`, not `result`

Comment: I think this should give the right result but the program does not accept it I will check if I made any mistake replacing variables

Comment: Right but the original never makes the extra list. Either way, I feel the poster should still provide some context because even as an exercise, this seems pretty horrible. Are they expecting a reimplementation of `min`, for instance?

Comment: @pvg - it is horrible but I made version without extra list - and now I don't need `min()` :)